# Converting weekly data to yearly data

Tags: r

I am new to R and I cant understand how to aggregate the weekly data i have to yearly data?

```
          Week obs
1   2004-01-04   23
2   2004-01-11   36
3   2004-01-18   18
4   2004-01-25   26
5   2004-02-01   17
6   2004-02-08   17
7   2004-02-15   26
8   2004-02-22   21
9   2004-02-29   34
10  2004-03-07   21
11  2004-03-14   30
12  2004-03-21   31
13  2004-03-28   31
14  2004-04-04   38
15  2004-04-11   14
16  2004-04-18   16
17  2004-04-25   44
18  2004-05-02   17
19  2004-05-09   43
20  2004-05-16   31
21  2004-05-23   31
22  2004-05-30   33
23  2004-06-06   13
24  2004-06-13   13
25  2004-06-20   46
26  2004-06-27   34
27  2004-07-04   27
28  2004-07-11   24
29  2004-07-18   20
30  2004-07-25   29
31  2004-08-01   29
32  2004-08-08   12
33  2004-08-15   16
34  2004-08-22   26
35  2004-08-29   29
36  2004-09-05   27
37  2004-09-12    8
38  2004-09-19   18
39  2004-09-26   14
40  2004-10-03   25
41  2004-10-10   26
42  2004-10-17   11
43  2004-10-24   24
44  2004-10-31   17
45  2004-11-07   11
46  2004-11-14   19
47  2004-11-21    8
48  2004-11-28   16
49  2004-12-05   19
50  2004-12-12   14
51  2004-12-19   13
52  2004-12-26   29
```

I want to just retain

```
2004 1215
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`, given `df$Week` is of class `Date` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,.(abs = sum(obs)), by = year(df$Week)]
#   year  abs
#1: 2004 1215
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R,

```
aggregate(df$obs, list(year = format(df$Week, '%Y')), sum)

#      year    x
# 1    2004 1215
```

or with `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
aggregate(df$obs, list(year = year(df$Week)), sum)

#      year    x
# 1    2004 1215
```

or with `lubridate` and `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(year = year(Week)) %>% summarise(obs = sum(obs))

# Source: local data frame [1 x 2]
# 
#    year   obs
#   (dbl) (int)
# 1  2004  1215
```